# Draw radius in meters using Maps API v3 Data layer based on GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Maps API v3 and added a GeoJSON file to create a circle (based on google.maps.Symbol objects) around each entry in the GeoJSON-file -- which works quite fine by using the *setStyle*-functionality:

```
map.data.addGeoJson('url_to_GeoJSON');
..
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 5,
    fillColor: '#f00',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 0
  }
  });
});
```

Now I would need to draw a circle with a static radius in meters around each point, like it is provided by the regular *google.maps.CircleOptions* with its '*radius*'.

Is there any possibility to use the very comfortable data layer '*addGeoJson*'- and '*setStyle*'-features in combination with a geographically correct radius in meters around each point?

I would be very happy to avoid setting up each marker manually "the old way" by iterating through the whole GeoJSON-file with

```
   new google.maps.Circle({radius: 20000});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

---

After adding the code of Dr. Molle, there seems to be an issue while using multiple google.maps.Data-Objects, that should be shown/hide by checking/unchecking a checkbox within the website. This is my actual code, which already shows the data layer with drawn circles, but does not hide the circles of the specific data layer when unchecking a checkbox:

```
var map;
var dataset1 = new google.maps.Data();
var dataset2 = new google.maps.Data();
var dataset3 = new google.maps.Data();

function initialize() {
   // Create a new map.
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
   zoom: 6,
   center: {lat: 50.678240, lng: 9.437256},
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
   });

   checkDataset();
}

function checkDataset() {
   if (document.getElementById('chkDataset1').checked) {

   // Define styles for dataPlug9 and apply to map-object.
   dataset1.setStyle(function(feature) {
      var geo = feature.getGeometry();

   // Check for a point feature.
   if(geo.getType().toLowerCase()==='point'){
      //create a circle
      feature.circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      center: geo.get(),
      radius: 200000,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.05,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeWeight: 1              
   });

   //trigger the dblclick-event of map.data on a dblclick on the circle
   google.maps.event.addListener(feature.circle, 'dblclick',function(e){
      e.stop();
      google.maps.event.trigger(this.getMap().data,'dblclick',   {feature:feature})
     });  

   // Hide the marker-icon.
   return {visible:false}; 
   }}); 

   // Remove feature on dblclick.
   google.maps.event.addListener(dataset1,'dblclick',function(f){
   this.remove(f.feature);
   });

   // Remove circle too when feature will be removed.
   google.maps.event.addListener(dataset1,'removefeature',function(f){
   try{f.feature.circle.setMap(null);}catch(e){}
   });

   dataset1.loadGeoJson('data/plug1.json');
   dataset1.setMap(map);
   } else {
      dataset1.removefeature();
      // This doesn't work either ..
      dataset1.setMap(null);
   }
}
```

I also added the above routine of function checkDataset() for the other 2 datasets (dataset2 and dataset3) and changed 'dataset1' to 'dataset2 / dataset3'.

Comment: What is *a geographically correct radius*

Comment: Sorry, should have explained this in more detail:

The drawn circle with a radius of i.e. 5,000 meters should always stay 5,000 meters on the map to visualise a range around the center. 
When you zoom out, the circle will be shown smaller but always be proportionately with 5,000 meters around the center on the map.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate "manually", `setStyle` already iterates over the features.

You may use it to execute additional code(e.g. create a `google.maps.Circle`):

```
        map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {  
        var geo=   feature.getGeometry();
        //when it's a point
        if(geo.getType().toLowerCase()==='point'){
         //create a circle
         feature.circle=new google.maps.Circle({map:map,
                                                center: geo.get(),
                                                radius: 20000,
                                                fillColor: '#f00',
                                                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                                                strokeWeight: 0});
         //and hide the marker when you want to
         return {visible:false}; 
        }});
```

---

### Edit:

related to the comment:

The circles will be saved as a `circle`-property of the features(note: this property is not a property in the meaning of geoJSON, so it may not be accessed via `getProperty`).

You may add a listener for the `removefeature`-event and remove the circle there, so the circle will be removed when you remove the feature.

Sample code that will remove a feature(including the circle) on `dblclick`:

```
   map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {  
        var geo=   feature.getGeometry();
        //when it's a point
        if(geo.getType().toLowerCase()==='point'){
         //create a circle
         feature.circle=new google.maps.Circle({map:map,
                                                center:geo.get(),
                                                radius:200000,
                                                fillColor: '#f00',
                                                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                                            strokeWeight: 0});

         //trigger the dblclick-event of map.data on a dblclick on the circle
         google.maps.event.addListener(feature.circle, 'dblclick',function(e){
           e.stop();
           google.maps.event.trigger(this.getMap().data,'dblclick',{feature:feature})
         });      

         //and hide the marker
         return {visible:false}; 
   }});



   //remove the feature on dblclick
   google.maps.event.addListener(map.data,'dblclick',function(f){
     this.remove(f.feature);
   });

   //remove the circle too when the feature will be removed
   google.maps.event.addListener(map.data,'removefeature',function(f){
     try{f.feature.circle.setMap(null);}catch(e){}
   });
```

Comment: Wow, your code snippet works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Would it on this way even be possible to remove the circles without saving them in an additional array and removing them by iterating through?

Comment: Hm, should this even be working when using multiple geoJSON files within google.maps.Data()-Objects which I want to show with circles and be able to hide each data layer separately? I included my code for this case in my first question. I guess, that theres a problem with my different maps.Data-Objects ..

Comment: Sorry, maybe my first posting with it's former topic is now more confusing than easily understable and helpful for other users:  Should I better start a new question for adding/removing circles on a data.set, even when multiple data-layers should be used on one single map?

Comment: Setting the `map`-property of the `Data`-instance to `null` will not `remove` the features from the instance, it will remove the layer from the map, but the instance will still contain the features. Therefore it's useless to observe the `removefeature`-event, because no feature will be removed when you set the `map`-property of the datasets to `null`. Instead bind the map-property of the circles to the map-property of the datasets. http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/5vtgn7w9/